# Python interpreter slowly pastes code

Tags: windows, python, windows-10, python3

When I first started using Python, the process of pasting code was fast; code I copied was pasted almost instantaneously into the interpreter. However, at some point roughly 6 months or so ago the interpreter started inputting pasted text more slowly, character by character (Another odd problem that arose at almost exactly the same time is that the pressing of the Tab key will now display all keywords instead of indenting).

I didn't investigate it at the time since I had more important things on my mind, and in the intervening time (during which I have switched from my original operating system, Windows 8.1, to Windows 10) the problem has gotten worse.

I have done some searching and haven't been able to find someone with a similar problem.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.
[image: The speed of pasting can vary]

However this problem does not hold up for a similar program such as the Windows command-line, which will paste text at the speed that I originally observed when I first started programming in Python. This leads me to believe that it may have been something that I unwittingly changed about the Python interpreter that may have caused this problem.

[image: This is the exact same text shown above being pasted into the Windows command line]

I'm wondering if some module I installed or setting I changed could have caused this problem and am looking for any suggestions that might help.

For reference, here is a list of the modules that I have installed (from pip).

- alabaster (0.7.4)
- APScheduler (3.0.3)
- autoenv (1.0.0)
- Babel (1.3)
- beautifulsoup4 (4.3.2)
- cffi (0.9.2)
- colorama (0.3.3)
- cryptography (0.8.1)
- cssselect (0.9.1)
- Cython (0.21.2)
- docutils (0.12)
- ecdsa (0.13)
- facebook-sdk (0.4.0)
- facepy (1.0.6)
- google-api-python-client (1.4.0)
- gTTS (1.0.4)
- httplib2 (0.9.1)
- idna (2.0)
- igraph (0.1.6)
- ipython (3.1.0)
- Jinja2 (2.7.3)
- libusb1 (1.4.0)
- MarkupSafe (0.23)
- matplotlib (1.4.3)
- mutagen (1.29)
- nltk (3.0.2)
- Nuitka (0.5.12.2)
- numpy (1.9.2)
- oauth2client (1.4.11)
- oauthlib (0.7.2)
- pbs (0.110)
- Pillow (2.7.0)
- pip (7.1.0)
- pocketsphinx (0.0.5)
- py2exe (0.9.2.2)
- pyasn1 (0.1.7)
- pyasn1-modules (0.0.5)
- PyAudio (0.2.8)
- pycparser (2.13)
- pydub (0.14.0)
- pygal (1.7.0)
- pygame (1.9.2a0)
- pyglet (1.2.2)
- Pygments (2.0.2)
- pymunk (4.0.0)
- pyOpenSSL (0.14)
- pyparsing (2.0.3)
- pyPdf (1.13)
- PyPDF2 (1.24)
- pyreadline (2.0)
- pytesseract (0.1.6)
- python-dateutil (2.4.2)
- python-firebase (1.2)
- python-Levenshtein (0.12.0)
- pyttsx (1.1)
- pytz (2015.4)
- pywapi (0.3.8)
- pywin32 (219)
- requests (2.6.0)
- requests-oauthlib (0.5.0)
- rsa (3.1.4)
- scapy-python3 (0.14)
- scikit-learn (0.15.2)
- scipy (0.15.1)
- setuptools (17.0)
- simplejson (3.7.2)
- six (1.9.0)
- snowballstemmer (1.2.0)
- SpeechRecognition (1.1.4)
- Sphinx (1.3.1)
- sphinx-rtd-theme (0.1.8)
- SQLAlchemy (0.9.9)
- svgwrite (1.1.6)
- sympy (0.7.6)
- textblob (0.9.0)
- Theano (0.7.0)
- tweepy (3.3.0)
- Twisted (15.0.0)
- tzlocal (1.1.3)
- uncertainties (2.4.6.1)
- UNKNOWN (0.0.0)
- uritemplate (0.6)
- virtualenv (12.0.7)
- virtualenvwrapper-win (1.2.0)
- wolframalpha (1.2)
- zope.interface (4.1.2)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2503794/3996968

Comment: @crazypotato While this alternative is something that I could use in the meantime, I'd still like to find a solution or cause for the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After resetting Windows and reinstalling Python, the problem disappeared. However, after I reinstalled **IPython** and **PyReadline** the problem reemerged. Uninstalling **PyReadline** resolved all of my original problems, but I want to know if anyone else encountered a similar problem with different modules.

Regardless, I will keep track of any other modules which cause these kinds of problems.

Comment: This worked for me in year 2021.

Comment: The old `pyreadline` is broken and have been migrated to `pyreadline3`. That said, any readline is trying to do various forms of command completion and thus trying to interpret each character as its being typed. `pyreadline` has no way to understand that something was being pasted, and thus try to process each character at the time. You can try to disable the command completion, and it will probably help somewhat.